# Can we get the connection string for an Application Insights in an Azure Resource Group Template?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, instrumentation

Can we retrieve the connection string for an Application Insights instance in an Azure Resource Group template ?

I can retrieve instrumentation key by below code but when I try to get connectionString with same or Listkey than it's giving error.

```
"outputs": {
    "MyAppInsightsInstrumentationKey": {
        "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('myAppInsightsInstanceName')), '2014-04-01').connectionString]",
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

Error :
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'myAppInsightsInstanceName' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#variables for usage details.'.","additionalInfo":[{"type":"TemplateViolation","info":{"lineNumber":95,"linePosition":40,"path":"properties.template.outputs.MyAppInsightsInstrumentationKey"}}]}}

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error you're getting.

Comment: updated error as well.

Comment: Can you try to use a newer API version?

Comment: The error message clearly indicates that you have not defined `myAppInsightsInstanceName` variable. Please try after fixing this error.

Answer (score 6):

As commented by @ZakiMa, you need to use a newer API version.

Something like that should work:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "variables": {
    "MyAppInsightsInstanceName": "<My App Insights Instance Name>"
  },
  "outputs": {
    "MyAppInsightsConnectionString": {
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('MyAppInsightsInstanceName')), '2020-02-02').ConnectionString]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": []
}
```